# How to add a subfolder in QtCreator project?

Tags: qt-creator

I had create a python project in QtCreator,the problem is I don't to how to add a subfolder in Qt project?

**The assets is a folder that I want to add**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your .pro file, you can add `OTHER_FILES *= yourFolder/*` It will add an entry in your project view on the left and index them to be able to use them easily (ctrl+k, ctrl+f etc.)

Comment: This python project, NOT C++ project

Comment: You can still make a pro file with only this "OTHER_FILES" tag and not use qmake.